# Caused: java.io.NotSerializableException: org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.scripts.ScriptApproval$PendingScript

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

In my declarative Jenkins pipeline I have added code which should approve scripts as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53731397/229864):

```
...
} catch (Exception jobFailed) {
   if (jobFailed.getMessage() == "script not yet approved for use") {
         echo("[WARNING] Changes in delivery job were automatically approved")
         approveDeliveryJob()
         return false
   }
...
@NonCPS
def approveDeliveryJob() {
    toApprove = ScriptApproval.get().getPendingScripts().collect()
    toApprove.each { pending -> ScriptApproval.get().approveScript(pending.getHash())} }
}
...
```

As suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45721262/java-io-notserializableexception-error-in-pipeline-scripting)

> to solve this put all the code that works with non serializable variables into `@NonCPS` annotated function

What I am missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
> toApprove = ScriptApproval.get().getPendingScripts().collect()
> ```

Here you are storing the result in the script binding, which is affected by serialization.

You need a local variable instead:

```
 def toApprove = ScriptApproval.get().getPendingScripts().collect()
```