# groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: years for class: java.lang.Integer

Tags: grails, groovy, timecategory

Even though I use it with TimeCategory like below:

`use (TimeCategory) {
      if (fromDate + 1.years < toDate) { ... }
    }`

and have an import at top (`import groovy.time.TimeCategory`) I get this error in a few times a day. What can be the cause? Is it a groovy/grails bug?

Comment: Have you double check if this is the line that produces this exception? You mentioned that you get this exception a few times a day - maybe there is a different place in the code where `1.years` gets called outside the `TimeCategory` use block?

Comment: Yes, the line is exactly where the if statement is.

Comment: Can't reproduce this issue with Groovy 2.4.12 and jdk1.8.0_162

Comment: It happens only once or twice a day.

Comment: If it is Jenkins related maybe look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42295921/what-is-the-effect-on-noncps-in-a-jenkins-pipeline-script . `@NonCPS` could help you.

Comment: I have the same problem. Once every 10k times we hit the code it will throw an error on ".days", ".months", or ".years". The link above at least gives me more to Google but nothing concrete yet. Was the OP ever able to solve this?

Comment: We noticed this exception in one of our QA environment. We are using  1.8.0_151-b12 jdk for running it. This code was compiled using `|Grails Version: 3.3.0
|Groovy Version: 2.4.11
|JVM Version: 1.8.0_9`.

Comment: After 5 years the problem is still here and nobody knows what the reason is :)