# Jenkinsfile takeWhile return Boolean on Jenkins but ArrayList in actual groovy. WHY?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

So, I have some code in a `Jenkinsfile` and the `takeWhile` function returns a boolean when run in jenkins but returns a list (as expected!) in an actual groovy execution. The whole script runs to conclusion locally but fails in jenkins because I am using the result of `takeWhile` as a `List` even though the jenkins version is a `Boolean`

My colleague theorizes that the plugin security manager is interfering. It's the only thing I can possibly imagine.

Local groovy version:

```
$ groovy -version
Groovy Version: 2.4.14 JVM: 1.8.0_131 Vendor: Oracle Corporation OS: Mac OS X
```

Jenkins version:

```
Jenkins ver. 2.107.3
```

Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy

try {
    def deployTo = [
            'pre' : ['us-east-1'],
            'int' : ['us-east-1'],
            's1'  : ['ca-central-1', 'us-east-1'],
            'demo': ['us-east-1'],
    ].collectMany { k, v -> v.collect { r -> [k, r] } }

    def failure = deployTo.findResult { entry ->
        def result = 0
        stage("Deploying to:\n${entry[0]}\n(${entry[1]})") {
            println("stage deploy")

        }
        return new Random().nextBoolean() ? entry : null
    }
    println("deployto is a : ${deployTo.class}")
    println("deploy to: ${deployTo}")
    def takeWhile = deployTo.takeWhile { it != failure }
    println("takeWhile is a : ${takeWhile.class}")
    println("takeWhile to: ${takeWhile}")
    takeWhile.each { toRollback ->
        println("torollback is a ${toRollback.class}")
        stage("Rolling back to:\n${toRollback[0]}\n(${toRollback[1]})") {
            println("stage rollback")
        }
    }
} catch (e) {
    println(e.getStackTrace().join('\n'))
    println(e.class)
    println(e.message)
    throw e
}
```

Local groovy output:

```
Deploying to:
pre
(us-east-1)
stage deploy
Deploying to:
int
(us-east-1)
stage deploy
deployto is a : class java.util.ArrayList
deploy to: [[pre, us-east-1], [int, us-east-1], [s1, ca-central-1], [s1, us-east-1], [demo, us-east-1]]
takeWhile is a : class java.util.ArrayList
takeWhile to: [[pre, us-east-1]]
torollback is a class java.util.ArrayList
Rolling back to:
pre
(us-east-1)
stage rollback
```

Jenkins output:

```
Running in Durability level: MAX_SURVIVABILITY
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Deploying to:
pre
(us-east-1))
[Pipeline] echo
stage deploy
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] echo
deployto is a : class java.util.ArrayList
[Pipeline] echo
deploy to: [[pre, us-east-1], [int, us-east-1], [s1, ca-central-1], [s1, us-east-1], [demo, us-east-1]]
[Pipeline] echo
takeWhile is a : class java.lang.Boolean
[Pipeline] echo
takeWhile to: false
No such getAt method found: method java.lang.Boolean[java.lang.Integer]. Administrators can decide whether to approve or reject this signature.
[Pipeline] echo
torollback is a class java.lang.Boolean
[Pipeline] echo
org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onGetArray(SandboxInterceptor.java:451)
org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$10.call(Checker.java:419)
org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedGetArray(Checker.java:424)
com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.SandboxInvoker.getArray(SandboxInvoker.java:45)
com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ArrayAccessBlock.rawGet(ArrayAccessBlock.java:21)
WorkflowScript.run(WorkflowScript:29)
com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.CpsDefaultGroovyMethods.each(CpsDefaultGroovyMethods:2030)
com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.CpsDefaultGroovyMethods.each(CpsDefaultGroovyMethods:1890)
WorkflowScript.run(WorkflowScript:27)
___cps.transform___(Native Method)
com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.PropertyishBlock$ContinuationImpl.get(PropertyishBlock.java:74)
com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.LValueBlock$GetAdapter.receive(LValueBlock.java:30)
com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.PropertyishBlock$ContinuationImpl.fixName(PropertyishBlock.java:66)
sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor703.invoke(Unknown Source)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationPtr$ContinuationImpl.receive(ContinuationPtr.java:72)
com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ConstantBlock.eval(ConstantBlock.java:21)
com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Next.step(Next.java:83)
com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:174)
com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:163)
org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport$ThreadCategoryInfo.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:122)
org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:261)
com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable.run0(Continuable.java:163)
org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.access$101(SandboxContinuable.java:34)
org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.lambda$run0$0(SandboxContinuable.java:59)
org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.GroovySandbox.runInSandbox(GroovySandbox.java:108)
org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.run0(SandboxContinuable.java:58)
org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThread.runNextChunk(CpsThread.java:174)
org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.run(CpsThreadGroup.java:332)
org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.access$200(CpsThreadGroup.java:83)
org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:244)
org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:232)
org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsVmExecutorService$2.call(CpsVmExecutorService.java:64)
java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
hudson.remoting.SingleLaneExecutorService$1.run(SingleLaneExecutorService.java:131)
jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28)
java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
[Pipeline] echo
class org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.RejectedAccessException
[Pipeline] echo
No such getAt method found: method java.lang.Boolean[java.lang.Integer]
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.RejectedAccessException: No such getAt method found: method java.lang.Boolean[java.lang.Integer]
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onGetArray(SandboxInterceptor.java:451)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$10.call(Checker.java:419)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedGetArray(Checker.java:424)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.SandboxInvoker.getArray(SandboxInvoker.java:45)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ArrayAccessBlock.rawGet(ArrayAccessBlock.java:21)
    at WorkflowScript.run(WorkflowScript:29)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.CpsDefaultGroovyMethods.each(CpsDefaultGroovyMethods:2030)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.CpsDefaultGroovyMethods.each(CpsDefaultGroovyMethods:1890)
    at WorkflowScript.run(WorkflowScript:27)
    at ___cps.transform___(Native Method)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.PropertyishBlock$ContinuationImpl.get(PropertyishBlock.java:74)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.LValueBlock$GetAdapter.receive(LValueBlock.java:30)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.PropertyishBlock$ContinuationImpl.fixName(PropertyishBlock.java:66)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor703.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationPtr$ContinuationImpl.receive(ContinuationPtr.java:72)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ConstantBlock.eval(ConstantBlock.java:21)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Next.step(Next.java:83)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:174)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:163)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport$ThreadCategoryInfo.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:122)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:261)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable.run0(Continuable.java:163)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.access$101(SandboxContinuable.java:34)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.lambda$run0$0(SandboxContinuable.java:59)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.GroovySandbox.runInSandbox(GroovySandbox.java:108)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.run0(SandboxContinuable.java:58)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThread.runNextChunk(CpsThread.java:174)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.run(CpsThreadGroup.java:332)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.access$200(CpsThreadGroup.java:83)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:244)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:232)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsVmExecutorService$2.call(CpsVmExecutorService.java:64)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at hudson.remoting.SingleLaneExecutorService$1.run(SingleLaneExecutorService.java:131)
    at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Finished: FAILURE
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is similar to an issue I filed ([JENKINS-49826](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-49826)). This is a CPS compilation problem in Jenkins Pipeline. I would file a bug against the [`workflow-cps-plugin`](https://plugins.jenkins.io/workflow-aggregator) as this is definitely not intended behavior.

In the meantime, I would move your `takeWhile` call to a `@NonCPS` annotated method and pass in all of the things as parameters. See [this question and answer for some information on `@NonCPS`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42295921/what-is-the-effect-on-noncps-in-a-jenkins-pipeline-script).

Here is your example reduced down to a small reproducer and a way you could move the logic to `@NonCPS`:

```groovy
final deployTo = [
  'pre' : ['us-east-1'],
  'int' : ['us-east-1'],
  's1'  : ['ca-central-1', 'us-east-1'],
  'demo': ['us-east-1'],
].collectMany { k, v -> v.collect { r -> [k, r] } }
final failure = [pre: 'us-east-1']

echo "${deployTo}"
echo "${deployTo.getClass()}"

def takeWhile = deployTo.takeWhile { it != failure }
println("takeWhile is a : ${takeWhile.class}")
println("takeWhile to: ${takeWhile}")

def nonCpsUsage = nonCpsTakeWhile(deployTo, failure)
println("nonCpsTakeWhile is a : ${nonCpsUsage.class}")
println("nonCpsTakeWhile to: ${nonCpsUsage}")

@NonCPS
def nonCpsTakeWhile(final d, final f) {
  return d.takeWhile { it != f }
}
```

And the output:

```
Started
Running in Durability level: MAX_SURVIVABILITY
[Pipeline] echo
[[pre, us-east-1], [int, us-east-1], [s1, ca-central-1], [s1, us-east-1], [demo, us-east-1]]
[Pipeline] echo
class java.util.ArrayList
[Pipeline] echo
takeWhile is a : class java.lang.Boolean
[Pipeline] echo
takeWhile to: true
[Pipeline] echo
nonCpsTakeWhile is a : class java.util.ArrayList
[Pipeline] echo
nonCpsTakeWhile to: [[pre, us-east-1], [int, us-east-1], [s1, ca-central-1], [s1, us-east-1], [demo, us-east-1]]
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
Finished: SUCCESS
```

Notice the different type that the returned type from `@NonCPS` is `java.util.ArrayList` compared to `java.lang.Boolean`.

Comment: Making uses of `stage` is pretty fundamental to what I am trying to do. but, your input was insightful (and, disappointing). Thanks