# Method in Jenkinsfile exits before completing

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have a Jenkinsfile which builds the same source for several different architectures and targets, and to facilitate this I have a method that builds for me. It is called like this:

```
stage('Build AMD64 image') {
    steps {
        dir("${env.WORKING_DIRECTORY}") {
            script {
                buildModule('storemanager', 'Dockerfile.amd64-slim', 'storemanager-0.0.1.jar', 'amd64')
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the method itself looks like this:

```
@NonCPS
def buildModule(module, dockerfile, jarfile, arch) {

    try {
        echo "Building ${arch} image"
        def dockerImage = docker.build("${env.IMAGE_NAME}", "--build-arg MODULE=${module} --build-arg JAR_FILE=${jarfile} --no-cache -f ${dockerfile} .")
        echo "${env.DOCKER_REGISTRY_URL} ${env.STOREMANAGER_REPOSITORY_CREDENTIALS}"
        docker.withRegistry("${env.DOCKER_REGISTRY_URL}", "${env.STOREMANAGER_REPOSITORY_CREDENTIALS}") {
            def tag
            echo "RELEASE: ${params.Release}"
            if (params.Release) {
                tag = "${BUILD_NUMBER}-${params.Version}-${arch}"
            } else {
                tag = "${BUILD_NUMBER}-${arch}"
            }
            echo "Pushing tag ${tag}"
            dockerImage.push(tag)
        }
    } catch (err) {
        currentBuild.result = 'FAILURE'
        throw err
    }
}


pipeline {
   // ....
}
```

This method stops running as soon as it has executed `docker.build`. Nothing else is printed to the console, no image is pushed to our repository. The build succeeds, but the resulting image is nowhere to be seen.

What am I doing wrong? Am I using Jenkins pipeline wrong, or is it a Groovy issue?

Comment: Probably not directly related, but you are using an undefined map `params` in your method.

Comment: Yes it is unrelated, `params` are resolved in the pipeline below and they work in the method.

Comment: Oh I missed that this is a scripted pipeline with the method inlined into the `Jenkinsfile`. I am accustomed to the shared lib/declarative approach for something like this.

Comment: Yes I am too, so this has been trial and error. We have a shared pipeline, but initially I want to ensure this works.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is the annotation `@NonCPS`:

> When you put @NonCPS on a method, Jenkins will execute the entire method in one go without the ability to pause. Also, you're not allowed to reference any pipeline steps or CPS transformed methods from within an @NonCPS annotated method.

Found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42295921/what-is-the-effect-of-noncps-in-a-jenkins-pipeline-script/42303407#42303407).