# Unable to serialize ListFilter in FilePath with groovy script on Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I want to run a groovy script on Jenkins to find and delete some files generated on nodes with a complex filter (filter in code below is just an simple example). This is my code:

```java
import hudson.util.*
import hudson.node_monitors.*

println "Jenkins version: $Jenkins.version "
println "Groovy version: $GroovySystem.version"
for (node in Jenkins.instance.nodes) {
    computer = node.toComputer()
    rootPath = node.getRootPath()

    if (computer.isIdle()) {
        def filesToDelete = rootPath.list({ File file -> 
                file.name.endsWith('.rpm')
            } as FileFilter)
        println(filesToDelete)

    } else {
        println("Skipping: Jobs are running on node")
    }
}
```

As documented [here](https://javadoc.jenkins.io/hudson/FilePath.html#list-java.io.FileFilter-) I use a `FileFilter`, which is embedded into a `ListFilter` according to code [here](https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins/blob/master/core/src/main/java/hudson/FilePath.java#L1831). Nevertheless I get a serialization error that I do not understand:

```
Jenkins version: 2.187 
Groovy version: 2.4.12
java.io.NotSerializableException: Script1
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1184)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:348)
    at java.util.LinkedHashMap.internalWriteEntries(LinkedHashMap.java:333)
    at java.util.HashMap.writeObject(HashMap.java:1363)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor6101.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1140)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1496)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:348)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest._serialize(UserRequest.java:264)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.serialize(UserRequest.java:273)
Caused: java.io.IOException: Unable to serialize hudson.FilePath$ListFilter@409cd9ba
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.serialize(UserRequest.java:275)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.<init>(UserRequest.java:101)
    at hudson.remoting.Channel.call(Channel.java:955)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:1072)
    at hudson.FilePath.list(FilePath.java:1831)
[...]
```

EDIT: Tested also with `@NonCPS` decorator and it return exactely the same error. Code here:

```java
import hudson.util.*
import hudson.node_monitors.*
import com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.NonCPS

println "Jenkins version: $Jenkins.version "
println "Groovy version: $GroovySystem.version"

@NonCPS 
def getList(path){ 
  return path.list( {File file -> file.name.endsWith('.rpm') } as FileFilter) 
}

for (node in Jenkins.instance.nodes) {
    computer = node.toComputer()
    rootPath = node.getRootPath()

    if (computer.isIdle()) {
        def filesToDelete = getList(rootPath)
        println(filesToDelete)

    } else {
        println("Skipping: Jobs are running on node")
    }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42295921/what-is-the-effect-of-noncps-in-a-jenkins-pipeline-script

Comment: @daggett I've try to use a class instead of a closure which implements `FileFilter` and `Serializable` with `accept` method with decorator `@NonCPS` but error is same without decorator.

Comment: you could keep closure. just declare a groovy function with @NonCPS annotation that returns file list.

Comment: @daggett same error with that method too

Comment: i mean like this: `@NonCPS def getList(path){ path.list( {File file -> file.name.endsWith('.rpm') } as FileFilter) }`

Comment: @daggett Yes that what's I did (you forgot `return`), but same error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197950/discussion-between-daggett-and-starfight).